# Block internet/network access to a specific application, or just to launch an application?

Tags: network, internet, firewall, ethernet

We have a legacy application which tries to force login at startup - but the server is not accessible. If there is no internet it just skips login (talk about security).

I have ethernet so I'm after the easiest way to disable network for just a couple of seconds, or for that app in general, rather than pulling cables or disabling my entire network adapter. Is this possible in an easy way?

Running Sierra.

Comment: [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html)

Comment: Neat @Tetsujin but $50 is a bit over the top for one application. I'd hoped maybe I might access a firewall, but I'm a windows guy

Comment: This is related but offers alternatives to LS only... not the other avenue of "just turn networking off momentarily" https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94282/which-free-alternatives-to-little-snitch-can-i-use-to-block-internet-traffic-per

Comment: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25673?locale=en_US

Comment: What's the name of the app and why does a /etc/hosts entry not work: `... 127.0.0.1 name_of_the_server ...`?

Comment: as a non-Mac expert I am nervous about hacking around with `sudo` - also I have no idea what server it is is trying to contact. If you can tell me how to find that out and block it in a way I can do safely, I'll accept the asnwer!

Comment: Need to know the name of the application in order to help out.  Turning off the network at startup isn't the best method to resolve this issue.  Can you please post the application name?

Comment: I mean you could make one up and I'll modify it... do you just need the name of the .app file... how does this work if I have multiple apps with the same name dotted around?

Comment: if you don't want to use the terminal there is the ["Gas Mask"](http://clockwise.ee/)  application that allows for editing the /etc/hosts file in a window. And to find out which server and port the application is trying to contact you can use Little Snitch: until you register it it's still fully functional for three hours at a time... and then you can uninstall it (the uninstaller is in the same .dmg file of the installer)