# Block Internet access to specific apps on specific Wi-Fi networks

Tags: network, wifi

My company just set my laptop up with Backblaze, and the backups are killing my crappy rural DSL connection when I bring the machine home. Are there utilities that can block specific applications from accessing the Internet on specific Wi-Fi networks?

I've seen recommendations here for apps like [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) or [Radio Silence](https://radiosilenceapp.com/) that can control Internet access on a per-app basis, but they don't seem to say anything about specific Wi-Fi networks. Can [Automator](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome/mac) control these apps when connecting/disconnecting from a specific Wi-Fi network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try TripMode, https://www.tripmode.ch

It is specific-network-aware, so you can activate it when you are on the constrained network, and after that it will remember, and auto-activate itself there.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm giving that a try.  Not seeing any per-network settings in TripWire though.  Are you saying TripMode will turn itself on or off when I change networks depending on what I had it doing on that network previously?

Comment: Yup, as the documentation says.

Answer (score 0):

*I was going to install a version of Little Snitch to test, but it requires me to restart my computer and I don't want to do that... Anyway:*

I'm pretty sure you can create a rule in Little Snitch to block Backblaze and then just toggle it on when you leave work and off when you get back.

[They have a free trial](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/download.html), so it is pretty trivial to test if you like the setup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'd rather configure an automated setup than have to turn it on and off every day.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also consider giving IceFloor a try too. It's FOSS. It was discussed previously on this site here: [Which free alternatives to Little Snitch can I use to block internet traffic per applications?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94282/which-free-alternatives-to-little-snitch-can-i-use-to-block-internet-traffic-per).

Main site: http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/index.html.